# Regex, extracting both word and number at the end of a string

Tags: regex

I'm a beginner to regex and encountered a problem and didn't find a solution, So let's say I have a string `ab123cd456`, I'm trying to find a regex expression that would extract the text untill the last number (if any) and the number itself so the result of the extraction would be `["ab123cd", "456"]`
extracting the end number is easily done by `\d+$`

but I am unable to make an expression to extract the `ab123cd` I've tried `.*(?=\d+$)` which extract `ab123cd45` which is weird to me because `+` is a greedy expression

Please note that I want a single expression for the task

Comment: `^.*\D|\d+$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBQO4b/2). Or, `^(.*\D)?(\d*)$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBQO4b/3). Or, `^(.*?)(\d*)$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBQO4b/4)).

Comment: You can consider `^.*\D(?=\d+$)`

Comment: `/^(.*[a-z])(\d+)$/i`

Comment: @anubhava, I like but don't see why you need `^`.

Comment: Or perhaps match till the end of the line, then backtrack until the last non digit and optionally match the digits at the end `^(.*\D)(\d*)$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fCJRsS/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Using `^` will be bit more efficient otherwise reegx will work without `^` also

Comment: coder, does any of the solutions work for you? What method/function do you use?

Comment: all of them worked great, I've found ```^.*\D|\d+$``` to be the best for my case as it only returns the two groups without the full string match which I find most convenient (i'm using the match function in javascript) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a non-greedy match as the first one:

```py
import re

lines = ["abc12cd1234"]

for line in lines:
    mre = re.match(r'(\w+?)(\d+)$', line)
    if mre:
        print mre.groups()
```

Will print:

```
('abc12cd', '1234')
```

Comment: `[\w\d]`  = `\w`

Comment: Right. Fixed that.